# How to use swift extension to get the IAP price in local currency

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am learning swift on my own and I cannot seem to figure out how to implement the extension below. I have an app on the App Store with a functioning IAP. But I now need to indicate the price in the local currency and not simply in US$ before the user clicks the button to buy.

I have read numerous posts about using an extension similar to the one below. However, I have been unable to get the cost to display as a String I can put in a label.

```
    extension SKProduct {
/// - returns: The cost of the product formatted in the local currency.
var regularPrice: String? {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = self.priceLocale
    return formatter.string(from: self.price)
}}
```

Among the methods I tried were:

```
label = SKProduct.regularPrice

label = product.regularPrice
```

I tried putting in my product ID ("com.afafaf.2323") but none of the attempts worked.

Yes, this is similar to some other posts, but none of them explain the implemtation to the extent I need.

I am clearly missing something easy, but I am not seeing it. Can someone please just show me how to use this extension properly?

Comment: You need to fetch your products via an [`SKProductsRequest`](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=skproductsrequest&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). Then you can access the `regularPrice` property of the `SKProduct` that is returned.

Comment: Thanks. I know I have that elsewhere where in my code. So I guess I need to look at adding that here. I think that makes sense. I'll give it a try. I just really don't want to mess up the IAP  code that is already working. 

Comment: A typical approach is to have an "IAP manager" class that requests the products and implements the transaction queue observer. You instantiate it in `didFinishLaunching` so that you have a transaction queue observer as soon as possible and your products are available when you need them.  You need the product before you can purchase it, so you should already have it when you are displaying your store interface.